# Error with sharing Android Studio project with GitHub

Tags: android, android-studio, github

So when I try to share my project with GitHub through Android Studio, it says I have done it successfully, and a new repository is created, but when I open the repository, it is empty. I'm pretty inexperienced with GitHub, and I have spent hours trying different things and I can't get it to work, so if someone could help point me in the right direction, I would be extremely appreciative.

Comment: Can you drop to the terminal real quick and post the output of git status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps for seamlessly working with Android Studio and github

1. Create a new project in Android Studio.
2. Create some files.
3. Go to **VCS** -> **Enable Version Control Integration.** Select git
4. Go to **VCS** -> **Commit File** and select all the files that you want to commit with a message.
5. Go to **VCS** -> **Push**.
6. Click on Define Remote.
7. Enter the url for the already created repository in github.
8. Click Push and enter the Github password.

P.S : I am using Android Studio version 1.5 If you are using some other version, then the steps can be a little different.

Comment: I think 5 and 6 should be switched... there is nothing to pull from at step 5

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error. I meant it to be git push not git pull.

Comment: That makes more sense :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I followed those steps and now there is a background task that says "Performing VCS commit..." but it's been going on for about an hour and I'm thinking it probably isn't supposed to be taking this long :)

Comment: Came back and tried it again and it decided to work this time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

After creating Repository, you have to push/commit the source files to the server. It seems you have not committed any file yet.

You can use some other Git clients like [Source Tree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview/)  with `GitHub`