# unable to share my android studio project to git the loading never end?

Tags: java, git, android-studio, github

When I try to share my project on git
i do the steps **VCS** -> **import Into Version Control** -> **Share Project On GitHub**, but Android Studio won't finish loading to create the repository.

I left my laptop open for 3 hours and it still didn't finish.

But when I open my git I found the repository but without any code

so i don't know how to commit my project.

This also happen  when i press at test button in Android Studio for path to git executable

[image: test button]

[image: loading never end]

**this is what i got**
[image: this is what i got]

Comment: Hi. You might want to check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000645/error-with-sharing-android-studio-project-with-github

Comment: i dont have these options in my VCS list

Comment: Have you installed git already? After you install it, you should have  `Enable Version Control Integration` option from your VCS

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to share your Android Studio project to Git.

1. Install Git from this [link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git?source=post_page---------------------------).
2. Go to **VCS** > **Enable Version Control Integration**.
3. Choose **Git** as you version control system.

You'll notice that your file will turn red. This means that you have not yet added these files to your source control.

4. Now, go to **VCS** > **Import into Version Control** > **Share Project to Github**.

Give your project a name and a description. Make sure to omit spaces.

5. Push your Project to Github. To push project **Ctrl + Alt + K** or go to **VCS** > **Git** > **Push**

Comment: i have installed get before but i delete it and download it again and i got this message (https://1.top4top.net/p_13074t1qz1.png) (https://2.top4top.net/p_1307n346y2.png)

Comment: then its start install and i got this message while install (https://1.top4top.net/p_13071v60z1.png) then its finish installing. in android studio i go to VCS list to do the  previous steps , for step number 2 it say i should do it from the setting (https://2.top4top.net/p_1307rz2db1.png) and when i press ok the program is lagging(stuck) till now i can't even close it ,i should shut down the laptop to close it

Comment: When you shut down your laptop and open it again, can you still do the Step 2?